# How to see my Picasa albums offline?

Tags: gallery, picasa

In other words how to download a picture from my Picasa album to my sdcard? I can see in the gallery but not have it in my phone :( so I cannot see when I don't have wifi. I don't want full sync but I want to save a pic which I see in gallery easily.

Update:

I have a good picture in my picasa web album.
When I am at my home with wifi, I can see the picture, show it to others. When I go out of wifi connection, If I try to see the picture I wont be able to because the image which was cached will be deleted and no longer available. I will just be able to see the thumbnail. Alternatively If there is an option to save the image to sd card in the gallery image viewer, I will save that particular picture to my sd card when I have wifi and view it anytime anywhere. So now, If I want to download a particular image of mine from picasa, I need to go to internet->picasawebalbums, browse for the same photo I can see in gallery and then download it. Is there a simple way of doing this? May be with anyother app?

Else, If I can access the cache folder where gallery caches picasa photos, I can copy from there. But I'm not able to find that too.

My phone model: Samsung Galaxy S LCD I9003

***Update:***
I found [this](https://market.android.com/details?id=larry.zou.colorfullife) app useful and allow me to save my photos but I cant browse friend's albums yet.

Answer (score 3):

You can sync Picasa albums to the web via a setting in the software on your computer. Google gives you a little storage for free.

Then on your phone you under Settings->Accounts and Sync, select the Google account and tick Sync Picasa Web Albumns.

Next time you open the Gallery app, it will show all the photos that have been uploaded to the web.

Comment: but only when I'm online.

Comment: Any albums you have viewed are still available when you go offline.

Comment: Not always. It depends on cache which is removed after some time.

Comment: This option doesn't exist for all users. I don't have it on my Samsung Intercept.

Comment: Picasa Web Albums don't seem to be a sync option any more under ICS/JB.

Answer (score 2):

Do I understand that your goal here is to save a single picture for offline viewing? If you access your photo via the stock browser rather than the Picasa app, you can long press on any image to bring up a menu of options including "save image" -- that will download the image to your SD Card.

I'm surprised that Picasa doesn't offer a similar option inside the app -- I'd at least try a long press there, too.

Comment: Long press in the gallery simply allows you to do multiple selections of albums: http://imgur.com/yTO5e

Answer (score 1):

[JustPictures!](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.justpictures) might be the app for you. It has excellent support for Picasa Web Albums and lets you download (sync) full albums to your phone. You can also save individual photos to your SD Card (open a photo, press menu, select save photo).

Highly recommended.

One limitation is that you may struggle to open other people's albums. [Related link](http://code.google.com/p/justpictures/issues/detail?id=392).

Answer (score 1):

The [Picfolio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snapwood.picfolio) App from Google Play downloads Picasa photos and thumbnails to my external SDCard. In settings, you specifiy which Picasa Web albums you want to cache on your phone and where to put them, external SDCard or internal.

Display still works when both WiFi and 4G data services are turned off on my Samsung Galaxy II (Gingerbread 2.3). (You have to turn both of these off if you want to really test app caching, at least on my phone.)

JustPictures! and PicasaTool produced good read-only cached album results only when there was a data service of some kind.

I just turned standard Android Picasa sync totally off, so that it doesn't mess up the sort order of photos taken only on my phone. The images are already there on PicFolio.

There is also an upload to Picasa option, but I have not used it yet. I use the Pro version, currently $2.99, to avoid advertisements.

I hope this helps others, as this thread certainly helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the USB cable to your computer and copy the image files from your computer to your device.

Alternatively, use Picasa on your computer to publish to Picasa Web Albums, but keep the album private.

Comment: That doesn't seem to answer the question.  If he copies it form his computer, it's not in Picasa, and if it's in picasa web albums, private or not, he can't view it in the gallery offline.

Comment: How else to do it, then? The image will still be in Picasa (unless he removes it) and he's not asking for it to be syncable. @balki: Please clarify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Gallery3D from XDA and sync it with your google account. It has a offline feature.

You can get it from here,

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=653503

Comment: I can't find Gallery3D from XDA. Did you mean this one? 
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cooliris.media&feature=search_result

Comment: @balki I think TuxGeek means the one you can find if you go to http://forum.xda-developers.com and search for "Gallery3D Apk" I'm not going to link directly to the thread here because I'm not sure of the legality of the app having been ripped out of the Nexus One image.

Comment: It sounds like he already has the gallery 3d on his device, which has been available in stock android 2.1+ (or 2.2).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this on my G2, thumbnails are stored and in some cases the full picture, but it is not consistent and there is no way to know which has been fully downloaded. The best way to view photos offline, is to manually download them from Picasa on your computer to your phone over USB.

It would be great if Google offered some way to know which albums were actually "synced" or if there was an option to download full resolution of all Picasa Albums for offline viewing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an app called [PhotoSuitcase](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.apparitionimaging.photosuitcase) where its primary use is to make your own Facebook, Picasa and Flickr available offline.